# setuptools_scm: how to append "-alpha" to package version upon merge in gitflow?

Tags: python, release, setuptools, packaging, semantic-versioning

My team uses:

- Gitflow: we have a `main` and a `develop` branch
- Semantic versioning per https://semver.org/
- [`setuptools_scm`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm) for our package version publishing

We would like to publish a bugfix version bump over the previous tag on `main` with some modification:

- Merges to `develop`: publish `-alpha` package
- Merges to `main`: publish `-beta` package

Here's an example:

1. Last tag on `main`: 1.2.3
2. Next merge to `develop`: 1.2.4-alpha
3. Next merge to `develop`: 1.2.4-alpha.1
4. Next merge to `develop`: 1.2.4-alpha.2
5. Finally a merge to `main`: 1.2.4-beta

...

Finally, a tag on `main` is manually made: 1.2.4

How can one accomplish stuff like this using `setuptools_scm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom version schemes with setuptools_scm: Here's the doc https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing/

:)